# How to reinstall Windows 7 boot manager if I accidentally removed the boot partition? (BitLocker enabled)

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, partitioning, bitlocker

(Nothing related to my other today post about installing Windows 10, it happened on another computer).

On my Lenovo T520 with Windows 7, I had 4 partitions:

- 100 MB partition
- 150 GB partition (C:\Windows), using BitLocker
- 700 GB partition (Data), using BitLocker
- 300 MB partition

I thought the two small partitions were unused, so I removed them with `diskmgmt.msc` and set the 150 GB system partition as "Active". Now the system does not boot anymore:

> Remove disks or other media. Press any key to restart.

I booted on a Windows 7 installation USB flash drive, entered in command line and did:

```
manage-bde -unlock c: -recoverypassword PASSWORDHERE
```

so the `C:` is now Bitlocker-unlocked. Then I did:

```
bootrec /fixmbr
bootrec /fixboot
bootrec /ScanOs
bootrec /rebuildBcd
```

and also:

```
c:\windows\system32\bcdboot c:\windows /s c:
```

All the messages basically said "Success".

After reboot, the problem is still there: `Remove disks or other media. Press any key to restart.`

**How to make my C: with Windows 7 (on a Bitlocker-protected partition) bootable again?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A second answer which is better/faster since it does **not** require to decrypt the whole disk (but I keep the other answer for future reference):

- Boot on a Windows 7 installation USB flash drive
- Temporarily suspend BitLocker on C:

  ```
   manage-bde -unlock c: -recoverypassword PASSWORDHERE
   manage-bde –Protectors –Disable C:
  ```
- Recreate a 300MB boot partition which is **not** BitLocker-encrypted:

  ```
  diskpart
  select disk 0
  create partition # for me a 300 MB did the job
  format
  active # make it bootable
  list volume
  select volume VOLUMENUMBER  # select the new partition
  assign letter=z
  exit
  ```
- Then do:

  ```
  bootrec /fixmbr
  bootrec /fixboot
  bootrec /nt60 sys /force /mbr    # i maybe tried  bootrec /nt60 c: /force /mbr and bootrec /nt60 z: /force /mbr as well
  ```

  and

  ```
  bcdboot c:\windows /s z:    # or was it bcdboot z: /s c: ? I don't remember
  ```
- Reboot, it should work!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if a better solution is possible but I finally did this:

- Boot on a Windows 7 installation USB flash drive
- Totally disable BitLocker on C:

  ```
  manage-bde -unlock c: -recoverypassword PASSWORDHERE
  manage-bde -off c:
  # then wait 1 hour and check it's done with:
  manage-bde -status
  ```
- Then

  ```
  bootrec /fixmbr
  bootrec /fixboot
  bootrec /ScanOs
  bootrec /rebuildBcd
  ```

  and

  ```
  c:\windows\system32\bcdboot c:\windows /s c:
  ```

  and

  ```
  diskpart
  select disk 0
  select partition NUMBERHERE
  active
  exit
  ```
- Reboot, it works!

Remark:

- This is not a very good solution since it required to disable BitLocker on C: but at least my system is not locked forever, and my files are back. I'll have to re-enable BitLocker now that the boot system is working again.
- After this, when trying to `Turn on auto-unlock` `D:\` on boot, I had this message: [Data error (cyclic redundancy check)](https://filestore.community.support.microsoft.com/api/images/91623b11-5bff-44c6-b6e7-59c0eb103071). Fortunately [this post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-hardware/bitlocker-drive-encryption-data-error-cyclic/f57aef6d-fd8d-4ac1-801c-475a72880023) gave the solution:

  ```
  manage-bde -autounlock -clearallkeys C:
  ```

  and reboot, then the "Auto unlock Bitlocker on boot" feature works again.
- I don't know why, but after all these steps, a new 300 MB partition has been automatically created, and this one is now the Active partition! Probably a boot partition?

Comment: This is actually the **only** solution to your problem.  Your actions made it necessary to disable the BitLocker protection on the disk.  You might have been alright with suspending the protection, but when doing any disk operation, you really should disable the protection.  This way you are not accidentally enabling the protections, which then require the recovery key, in order to boot Windows.

Comment: if I don't have bitlocker issues, but just a Windows 7 install that won't boot, shoot I then start my fix with with this step: " **bootrec /fixmbr** "
 ??